# Django rest APIs, automate documentation?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, api-doc, django-swagger

I tried documenting the APIs while writing viewsets and using [django rest docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/documenting-your-api/). I am having the following problems:

- if I try to send values for reverse related field, it takes list of values, but when sending the data in Form-data, it comes as a string.
- There is no option for file upload in the docs UI.

Following is my code:

models.py

```
class Area(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='area/')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-modified_on',)



class Email(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    email = models.EmailField()
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='email')


class Phone(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='phone')
```

view.py

```
class AreaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    create:
    Create a new area instance.

    """
    serializer_class = AreaSerializer
    parser_classes = (FormParser, MultiPartParser,FileUploadParser)
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [AllowAny, ]
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('first_name',)

    def create(self, request):
        data = self.request.data
        with transaction.atomic():
            name = data['name']
            address = data['address']
            email = json.loads(data['email'])
            phone = json.loads(data['phone'])
            zipcode = data['zipcode']

            area = Area.objects.create(name=name,address=address, zipcode=zipcode)

            for i in email:
                Email.objects.create(email=i['email'], area = area)

            for i in phone:
                Phone.objects.create(phone=i['phone'], area=area)

            return Response({'status': {'code': status.HTTP_200_OK,
                                        'error': None,
                                        'message':' Area has been added.'
                                        },
                             'data': None})
```

serializer.py

```
class AreaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = EmailSerializer(many=True)
    phone = PhoneSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Area
        fields = '__all__'
```

i am using 
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/documenting-your-api/

There is no file upload in image field in default docs.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide your area model?

Comment: yes , i have updated question with models

Comment: Try `serializer = AreaSerializer(data=request.data)` and `return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Cbzyh0CT try this

Comment: ya tried it above solution , it was not working , it will also give errors nested serializer write operations is not allowed for phone and email

Comment: What version of DRF are you using?

Comment: drf 3.7 and django 2.0.4

Answer (score 2):

Another good idea would be to use [Swagger](https://swagger.io/). In Django, especially using DRF, you have the opportunity to integrate with [Django Rest Swagger](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger) and generate automatic documentation for your endpoints. The only requirement is to provide with docstrings-documentation your API classes and methods.

ps: I have no affiliation with django rest swagger package or authors, just a frequent user

Comment: [Django Rest Swagger](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger) is deprecated since 2019-06-04. The library developer - and DRF docs as well - recommend users to use [drf-yasg - Yet Another Swagger Generator](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg/) instead.

Answer (score -4):

Ok first , to be more pratical, your  create function needs to be like this

```
def create(self,request, *args,**kwargs):
       data = request.data
       logger.debug("%s" % data)
       request = (self.__dict__['request'])
       #parse the rest of your code here
```

Also , why can't  you swagger to easily set up your documentation it's going to be more easier for you, or maybe it's a requirement for you

Comment: i dont understand :D